# React mobx inject store into component

Tags: reactjs, mobx, mobx-react

When we call mobx and inject and observe store inside component in following way

```
**ExampleStore.ts**
import { observable, action } from 'mobx';

export class ExampleStore {
    @observable
    testData1: any = [];

    @observable
    testData2: any = [];

}
```

and

```
export default inject('exampleStore')(observer((props) => {
    // Return component
    // Uses testData1 only
}));
```

**Is testData2 injected into React component as well? or only testData1 that is used is injected?**

Answer (score 1):

Both observables are accessible within the component, but the component will only re-render when one of the **used** observables changes.

Check [mobx react integration documentation](https://mobx.js.org/react-integration.html) for  more details:

> The observer HoC automatically subscribes React components to any observables that are used during rendering.